# Should [formula] be a synonym of [mathematics]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Bringing this here, since I don't have permissions to suggest synonyms.

The [formula](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula) tag currently has only 34 questions, and no tag info. The current explanation for [mathematics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) includes "formulae."

> Mathematics questions deal with the arithmetic, geometry, calculus, formulae and other calculations used in the development of a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think [formula](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula) should be made a synonym of [mathematics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics).

The rationale behind it is that if you ask for a formula, you're facing the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/303557).

A formula implies a "single of code", which is IMHO very generic. An algorithm or some mathematics is generally what one should ask about. Good if the answers suggest a single-line formula.

Comment: I was at first thinking `formula` as a synonym of `algorithm` but algorithm is based on many steps, and figuring a mathematic formula would be a singular step or not even involved in an algorithm.

Comment: @Chris I think the concept of "algorithm" is a subset of the field of the "mathematics", but I think in our context we can have them separate :P

Comment: For this I don't have permissions to even suggest the synonym.

Comment: @Chris You can ping Josh about it in chat about it.

Comment: This has been done.