# Should we add a loot tag (or something similar)?

Tags: discussion, tags

It was [proposed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60000774#60000774) that we adopt a tag for "stuff given to the player in a way that involves random numbers".

We currently have 225 [posts containing "loot"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=loot) and another 6 [posts containing drop-rate](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22drop+rate%22+-frame+-loot) (minus "loot" and "frame-rate" to avoid double counts & posts about performance respectively).

Possibly related reading: meta discussion about [mathematics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) that [mentions loot](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2513/33287). I didn't see anything else on meta that touched on it.

Does adding a loot tag better facilitate questions about this topic and if so, what should the term be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's helpful. Presently it's covered inconsistently with an assortment of other tags. Loot based questions are asked often enough to warrant a specifier, but not so often that such a tag would be tiresome. It's possible to have expertise on the topic. The topic isn't ambiguous and doesn't seem like it would be a meta-tag.

I propose the term `loot-system`. It would cover things like procedural generation of loot as well as the distribution of loot to players. It also happens to also be listed on [Wikipedia's glossary of video game terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_video_game_terms).

Comment: The "loot system" described on Wikipedia is specific to multiplayer games to distribute the loot among a subset of players. I wonder if using the term loot-system to describe the more global generation of drops is appropriate.

Comment: I've used the term "loot system" in my own work in single-player contexts, but that's just one data point.